# Show that for the polynomial $px^5 + x^3 + q$, where $p$ and $q$ are odd prime numbers, there are no rational roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

With the rational root theorem I get that the only possible roots are $\pm 1, \pm \dfrac{1}{p}, \pm q, \pm \dfrac{q}{p}$. And the only thing I could think of was to use Vieta's formulas for the product and sum, where it is intuitive that the five roots (with the above 8 to choose from) will not give a sum of $0$ and product of $-\dfrac{q}{p}$.

I also tried substituting $\dfrac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, with hopes of ending up with a contradiction using modular arithmetic, but I sort of got lost in my own reasoning.

Are there any clever, elegant ways to show this?

Comment: Why not just check each of the possible roots?

Comment: Should note: I don't see any way to apply Vieta here.  The rational root theorem certainly does not say that $\textit {all}$ of the roots have to be rational or anything like that.  A priori it is perfectly possible that one of those $8$ is a root but that the other four are complex numbers.  I really think testing the $8$ is the way to go.  I mean, it can be done in your head.

Answer (score 4):

You can eliminate all 8 possibilities pretty easily.  First, all the coefficients of the polynomial are positive.  If you plug in any positive number, you'll get a positive, so none of the positive choices can be roots.  That's 4 down, 4 to go.

Now suppose you choose a potential root with $q$ in the numerator.  Plug it in and re-arrange the equation so that one side is exactly divisible by $q$, but the other side is divisible by at least $q^3$.   Two more down.

Plug in $-1$ and get $-p-1+q = 0.$  Nope, not if $p$ and $q$ are both odd.  One left.

Plug in $-1/p$ and multiply through by $p^3$.  Is $1$ a multiple of $p$?  Nope.  Done.

Comment: Thank you! This might be a dumb question, but how can we be sure that the roots with q in the numerator can't be roots after re-arranging them so that one side is exactly divisible by $q$ and the other side is divisible by at least $q^3$? Like in the case with $-\dfrac{q}{p}$ I can't convince myself it's not a possible root.

Comment: @femnollnoll  If you put the constant term on the other side you have  $px^5 +x^3 = -q.$  If a proposed root has q in the numerator, then $q^3$ divides the left side, but not the right.